# How to format a number 1000 as "1 000"

Tags: ruby, function, formatting, numbers

I need a way to format numbers. I stored some numbers in my DB table, e.g. `12500`, and would like to print them in this format `12 500` (so there is a space every 3 digits). Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: number_with_delimiter(12500, delimiter: " ")

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no built in way to it ( unless you using Rails, ActiveSupport Does have methods to do this)  but you can use a Regex like

```
formatted_n = n.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse
```

Comment: that will add commas, not spaces btw

Comment: Just replace the ampersand with a space (`\&,` with `\& `) and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick help. But, tell the truth, I thought that exist some nicer way (e.g. something like [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in PHP). But how I am saying, thanks for solution!

Comment: Here's a modification that handles negative numbers too: `n.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?!-)(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse`. For example: "-174", not "-,174".

Comment: The Rails / ActiveSupport method mentioned is [Numeric#to_formatted_s](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-to_formatted_s)

Comment: Here's a variant, to avoid the two `reverse`'s: `str=n.to_s; f=str.size%3; str[0,f] << str[f..-1].gsub(/.../, ' \&')`.

Comment: Is there a way to deal with float numbers? The method above gaves me the following result: "1,231,213,213,213,.33" - with an extra comma at then end, together with the dot separator

Comment: @mickael You could change the `.`'s to match only numbers instead of anything. I don't recall the exact syntax of ruby regexes these days but something like `/[0-9]{3}(?=[0-9])/` or along those lines.

See steenslag's answer below also

Answer (score 23):

Activesupport uses this regexp (and no reverse reverse).

```
10000000.to_s.gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1 ") #=> "10 000 000"
```

Comment: I'd would open the Integer class and add a method. That catches Fixnum and Bignum.

Comment: That's rather nice. Could the negative look-ahead be eliminated with `/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/`?

Answer (score 13):

Here's another method that is fairly clean and straightforward if you are dealing with integers:

```
number.to_s.reverse.scan(/\d{1,3}/).join(",").reverse

number            #=> 12345678
.to_s             #=> "12345678"
.reverse          #=> "87654321"
.scan(/\d{1,3}/)  #=> ["876","543","21"]
.join(",")        #=> "876,543,21"
.reverse          #=> "12,345,678"
```

Works great for integers. Of course, this particular example will separate the number by commas, but switching to spaces or any other separator is as simple as replacing the parameter in the `join` method.

Comment: ```formatted_n = n.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse``` faster than this solution ;)

Comment: @Matrix which is probably why that is the top reply to this question :) I was just adding my take on the problem. I love Ruby because there's always a hundred different ways to do things!

Comment: you seem to take my comment as an attack, it does not have, I just read the various solutions, because the "top" is not always the best in fact. So I did a benchmark test and I give my conclusion that want to hear it. Nothing more ;)

Answer (score 11):

The [official document](http://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/man/html/_C0B5B5ACC9BDB8BD.html#a.a5.b5.a5.f3.a5.d7.a5.eb) suggests three different ways:

1) Using lookbehind and lookahead (Requires [oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/))

```
12500.to_s.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\z)/, ' ')
# => "12 500"
```

2) Using only lookahead. Identical to steenslag's answer.

3) Using neither lookahead nor lookbehind

```
s = 12500.to_s
nil while s.sub!(/(.*\d)(\d{3})/, '\1 \2')
s # => "12 500"
```

Comment: #3 appears to rely on greediness. If so, I'd think it wouldn't matter if `gsub!` or `sub!` were used. `nil` could be replaced with any literal. Correct? Is that always equivalent to `while s.gsub!(/(.*\d)(\d{3})/, '\1 \2'); end` (which I think reads a bit better)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes. `gsub!` was unnecessary. I edited.

Answer (score 6):

very simple:

`number_with_delimiter(12500, delimiter: " ")`

see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_delimiter

Comment: This is not for ruby, this is only rails method

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
12500.to_s.reverse().split(//).inject() {|x,i| (x.gsub(/ /,"").length % 3 == 0 ) ? x + " " + i : x + i}.reverse()
```

You can always Open the Fixnum class and add this for convenience:

```
module FormatNums
  def spaceify
    self.to_s.reverse().split(//).inject() {|x,i| (x.gsub(/ /,"").length % 3 == 0 ) ? x + " " + i : x + i}.reverse()
  end
end

class Fixnum
  include FormatNums
end

12500.spaceify # => "12 500"
```

Comment: Oh, a wiseguy, are ya? Very nice! +1 :)

Comment: @Yardboy thanks. With Ruby it isn't built in because you can build it in yourself so easily. Right?

Comment: Indeed. Coding for the sake of coding, what could be better?

Answer (score 3):

So, this is pretty crazy and hackish, but it gets the job done...

```
12500.to_s.split("").reverse.each_slice(3).map {|y| y.join("").reverse}.reverse.join(" ")
 => "12 500" 

.to_s: convert to string
.split(""): split into separate digits
.reverse: reverse order
.each_slice(3): peel of each three digits (working from back end due to reverse)
.map {|y| y.join("").reverse}: map into an array for each three digits - join back together with no delimiter and reverse order back to original
.reverse: reverse order of mapped array
.join(" "): join mapped array back together with space delimiter
```

Comment: This is clever to use `each_slice` to avoid redundant regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

All but one of the answers use `n.to_s`. @MrMorphe's does not, but he creates an array to be `join`ed. Here's a way that uses neither [Fixnum#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) nor [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

```
def separate(n,c=' ')
  m = n
  str = ''
  loop do
    m,r = m.divmod(1000)
    return str.insert(0,"#{r}") if m.zero?
    str.insert(0,"#{c}#{"%03d" % r}")
  end
end

separate(1)       #=>         "1"
separate(12)      #=>        "12"
separate(123)     #=>       "123"
separate(1234)    #=>     "1 234"
separate(12045)   #=>    "12 045"
separate(123456)  #=>   "123 456"
separate(1234000) #=> "1 234 000"
```

Hmmm. Is that column on the right tipping?

Another way that uses `to_s` but not `join`:

```
def separate(n, c=' ')
  str = n.to_s
  sz = str.size
  (3...sz).step(3) { |i| str.insert(sz-i, c) }
  str
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old but the fastest and most elegant way I could find to do this is:

```
def r_delim(s, e)                                                               
  (a = e%1000) > 0 ? r_delim(s, e/1000) : return; s << a                        
end

r_delim([], 1234567).join(',')
```

I'll try and add benchmarks at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
Here "delimiter is `' '`(space), you can specify `','` for money conversion."

```
number.to_s.reverse.gsub(%r{([0-9]{3}(?=([0-9])))}, "\\1#{delimiter}").reverse
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to [so]! You're welcome, and congratulations on your first upvote (from me :D) By the way, take a [tour], and you can chat in a relevant [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this thread while looking for a way to format a value as US currency.  I took a slightly different approach to the regex solutions proposed:

```
amt = 1234567890.12
f_amt = format("$%.2f",amt)
i = f_amt.index(".")
while i > 4
  f_amt[i-3]=","+f_amt[i-3]
  i = f_amt.index(",")
end

f_amt
=> "$1,234,567,890.12"
```

This could be parameterized for formatting other currencies.

Answer (score -2):

I'm aware this is an old question but.

why not just use a substring substitution.

in pseudo code....

```
String numberAsString = convertNumberToString(123456);
int numLength = V.length;//determine length of string

String separatedWithSpaces = null;

for(int i=1; i<=numlength; i++){//loop over the number
separatedWithSpaces += numberAsString.getCharacterAtPosition(i);
    if(i.mod(3)){//test to see if i when devided by 3 in an integer modulo,
    separatedWithSpaces += " ";

    }//end if

}//end loop
```

I know it isn't in any particular languange, but hopefully you get the idea.

David

Comment: I'd think regular expressions are the best and cleanest way to solve this problem. This hear looks way too complicated.