# Parse a number using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I would like to take a number and format it as price (as a string).  For example I want to take 250000 and display $250,000.  How can I accomplish this using regex?

Comment: AFAIK, regex can't loop. Are you guaranteed an upper bound on the number?

Comment: Yes. Assume the number is bounded.

Comment: So, would $999,999 be an acceptable upper bound?

Comment: To put the commas you need to know the number of digits, this can't be achieved with regex only

Comment: Yes that would be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For adding the commas you could give something like this a try:

```
/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/
```

Then replace every match with `\1,`.

As such:

```
"12345512312".gsub(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/,'\1,')  => "12,345,512,312"
```

This would match any digit followed by an arbitrary number of 3 digit groups.

**E.g.** the first `2` in the above example is followed by 3 groups: `345`, `512` and `312`. The first `5` is followed by 2 groups: `512` and `312`, etc.

Not sure if you'll be able to add the `$` in the same regex though.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the `?:` works? It doesn't seem like it is necessary.

Comment: Strictly speaking the `?:` is not necessary, all it does is make the grouping `\d{3}` a passive group (meaning no back-reference is created). We need to make this a group because we want to match 1 or more occurrences of `\d{3}`.

We could've done `(\d{3})+`, but then `\2` would've back-referenced the matching numbers. In this case it would've made no difference, but it keeps it cleaner and makes the intent clearer when we use passive groups.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one out (disclaimer- not a regex):

```
def prettify(n)
  int, dec = n.to_s.split('.')
  int = int.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/).join(',').reverse
  [int, dec].reject(&:empty?).join('.')
end
```

Probably a gem out there for this kind of thing though

Answer (score 2):

Matching with regex it's a pain in the #@! in this case since regex engines begin matching from the beginning of the string, not the end (finding 3 digit patterns beginning at the end of the string and going backwards). I'd suggest either doing something like this:

```
format_int = ->(s) do
  str = s.reverse.scan(/\d{1,3}/).join(',').reverse
  "$#{str}"
end

format_int['2500600'] => "$2,500,600"
```

... using [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (this can be a little tricky) or, as you wanted: 
I was wrong, it can be achieved with regex as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458990/how-to-format-a-number-1000-as-1-000) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078347/is-there-a-rails-trick-to-adding-commas-to-large-numbers).

Comment: This is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

you should be using the `number_to_currency helper`

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.50)                    # => $1,234,567,890.50
number_to_currency(1234567890.506)                   # => $1,234,567,890.51
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, precision: 3)     # => $1,234,567,890.506
number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)      # => 1 234 567 890,51 €
number_to_currency("123a456")                        # => $123a456

number_to_currency("123a456", raise: true)           # => InvalidNumberError

number_to_currency(-1234567890.50, negative_format: "(%u%n)")
# => ($1,234,567,890.50)
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, unit: "&pound;", separator: ",", delimiter: "")
# => &pound;1234567890,50
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, unit: "&pound;", separator: ",", delimiter: "", format: "%n %u")
# => 1234567890,50 &pound;
```

for more info look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html